# How can I customize Android Gallery component?

Tags: android, android-gallery

I would like to show Photogallery using the Android Gallery component but I would like to show a description text under every single image.
How can I do? I've only found examples using only images or only text.

Answer (score 1):

You can put any sort of View in your Gallery. For example you can have a LinearLayout combining ImageView and TextView, or derive ImageView.onDraw to draw a text.

Comment: Please can you post a snippet of code about it? If i put Views inside a Gallery how can assign content to them?